# Are two creatures sharing one square adjacent to each other?

Tags: dnd-4e, creature-size

**If a Tiny creature (like a Pixie) shares a square with a Medium creature (say human), are they considered adjacent to each other?**

> **Adjacent Squares:** Two squares are adjacent if a side or a corner of
>   one touches a side or a corner of the other. Two creatures or objects
>   are adjacent if one of them occupies a square adjacent to a square
>   occupied by the other.

I can see a topological argument that by its very nature the corners and sides of a square are touching other corners and sides of the same square. Is this a case of nitpicking the RAW to pieces? What are the ramifications?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. they are adjacent.

From the pixie entry:

"Two creatures are considered adjacent if they are in the same square" (Heroes of the Feywild p28)